# Insert picture into an mp4 video, probably using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I need to insert an image into a video of mp4 format. The image has smaller dimensions than the video, will appear after the video starts, say, after a minute and a half at certain x, y coordinates of the video frame, will stay on (full opacity) for some time and then will disappear before the video finishes.

It would also be good if the image "fades in" / "fades out" when appearing / disappearing from the video.

I would like to do that using the latest ffmpeg 4.1.1, although I am also open in using other opensource programs that run under linux if it would be achieved easier.

I have the `ffmpeg` build with `--enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx` if this may help.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: if you just need to do this once, and NLE like davinci resolve or something would be the way to go... if you need to automate it, you should contact the ffmpeg users group email https://ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/ffmpeg-user

Comment: @Grady Player It needs to be automated.